# What's wrong with my Scarlet Oak tree?

Tags: diseases, oak

My poor Scarlet Oak (Quercus coccinea) tree started getting brown/yellow leaves with holes in them. Any ideas as to what the problem is?

It's been really dry and the tree is less than one year old in this location.

[image: Scarlet Oak brown leaves]

[image: Scarlet Oak brown leaves]

[image: Scarlet Oak brown leaves]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you been watering the tree since it has been dry?  In their first year of getting established, trees may need help keeping moist.  Water this tree with a hose for a solid two minutes, taking little breaks to allow the water to percolate into the ground and not just flow away.  Apply mulch of some sort around the base of the tree, keeping a gap around the trunk at a depth of about 3".  That will help with moisture retention